# Generic check for a const string a valid enum value

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum MimeType {
  VideoMP4 = 'video/mp4',
  VideoQuicktime = 'video/quicktime',
}
```

I would like to be able to infer the enum value from a string input to a function:

```
function createSomething<const V extends `${string}:${MimeType}`>(value: V): V extends `${string}:${infer M}` 
  ? M extends MimeType 
    ? Something<M>
    : never
  : never;
```

Where `type Something<M extends MimeType> = ...`;

In the above `createSomething`, I always get `never`. The part of the ternaries that appears to fail is `M extends MimeType`. For example:

```
type Test1 = 'video/mp4' extends MimeType ? true : false; // false
```

However:

```
type Test2 = 'video/mp4' extends MimeType[keyof MimeType] ? true : false; // true
```

But that does not become compatible with `Something`.

I have also tried:

```
function createSomething<M extends MimeType, const V extends `${string}:${M}`>(value: V): Something<V>;
```

But that generalises `M` to `MimeType` even when passing in a specific `V`, probably because it still cannot infer M to a specific enum member.

Is there a way to assert that a string (const type) is a valid value of an enum at the type level?

Comment: What's the reason behind the colon (`:`) in the template literal? Could you maybe add an example of how you would like to call `createSomething(?)`?

Comment: I'm not going to add it to the question because the question is not about the context. But if it helps, I'm serialising a media asset reference into its ID and mimetype. The serialised convention I'm using is to delimit those two attributes using `:`, because neither of the attributes will include that character. I then want to be able to parse that serialised string back into the attributes ID and mimetype.

Comment: Hmm, I see you've opened 2 questions about enums in a short time; can you [edit] to clarify the difference so that nobody closes one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, they are similar. This one addresses using enums. [The other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77591154/why-does-a-specific-string-not-conform-to-enum-including-that-string) was specifically about the type theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) types in TypeScript are considered to be [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) *subtypes* of their values.  That is, `MimeType.VideoMP4` is assignable *to* the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `'video/mp4'`, but crucially *not vice versa*.  Enum values are supposed to be mostly opaque to your code; one of the purposes of using an enum is to require that you actually use the enum.  So

```
const okay: MimeType = MimeType.VideoMP4;
```

is always correct no matter what the value turns out to be, while

```
const bad: MimeType = "video/mp4"
```

is always an error even if the value turns out to be in the enum.  It's one of the few places in the language where types are treated nominally.  If you don't like this behavior, you might not actually want an enum at all.

[As mentioned in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums), you might just want a [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) object instead:

```
const MimeType = {
  VideoMP4: 'video/mp4',
  VideoQuicktime: 'video/quicktime',
} as const;
type MimeType = typeof MimeType[keyof typeof MimeType];
```

which makes your code work as-is:

```
const x = createSomething("abc:video/mp4");
//    ^? const x: Something<"video/mp4">
const y = createSomething("def:video/quicktime");
//    ^? const y: Something<MimeType.VideoQuicktime>
const z = createSomething("ghi:video/oops"); // error
```

---

If you insist on using enums you can still salvage `createSomething()` by using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) and an [`extends` constraint inside an `infer` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables):

```
declare function createSomething<
  const V extends `${string}:${MimeType}`>(value: V): V extends `${string}:${infer M}`
  ? M extends `${infer MM extends MimeType}` ? Something<MM> : never : never;
```

This prompts the compiler to infer `MM` as a subtype of `MimeType` that, when serialized as a string, is `M`. It works too:

```
const x = createSomething("abc:video/mp4");
//    ^? const x: Something<MimeType.VideoMP4>
const y = createSomething("def:video/quicktime");
//    ^? const y: Something<MimeType.VideoQuicktime>
const z = createSomething("ghi:video/oops"); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-P8hIgmCEJQrgn4QHCiLIhgqK6PImL2Ey76AihJJoRSwBUn0NKEuyDKvohBJEpS1L8ExzKLi0sKEhyMHOhxOyChKtEiSKfRSj6qZyv6gYqpm9barqzbusaprpEmXA2okMlLBmdaCTmED5gEGiaGW3AyX6VbyQJobhqpZ4xpe8aaZa2kpskSDppyhlzJhpmOIeJYQJZuneZWUG1mqSmNoITkmK27adt2fS9v2tj-tEQA)