# Why does a specific string not conform to enum including that string?

Tags: typescript, enums

If I have enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  foo = 'FOO',
  bar = 'BAR',
}
```

the result of testing for confirmance of a const string behaves like:

```
type StringIsInEnum = 'FOO' extends MyEnum ? true : false; // false
```

Can someone explain why in this case, `'FOO'` does not extend `MyEnum`?

`MyEnum.foo` will never change during runtime, and `'FOO'` is a constant value, and so will also never change.

Comment: TS enums behave like nominal *subtypes* of their values, to prevent you from mixing them up with their values.  So `MyEnum.foo extends 'FOO'` but not vice versa. You can serialize `MyEnum` to widen it, like `'FOO' extends \`${MyEnum}\` ? true : false`.  But if your code depends on the values, you probably don't want an enum to start with; just use a `const` object instead like `const MyEnum = {foo: "FOO"; bar: "BAR"} as const` and if you need it, `type MyEnum = typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum]`. Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, I see you've opened 2 questions about enums in a short time; can you [edit] to clarify the difference so that nobody closes one as a duplicate of the other?  Right now it looks like this one is a clarification of the other one.  Is it possible to get an answer for one that doesn't answer the other too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TypeScript is generally a *[structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing)* language `enum`s are a bit of an exception. They are designed to be *nominal* or *opaque*. Therefore, you can't compare them with string values.

However, there are workarounds...

```
enum MyEnum {
  foo = 'FOO',
  bar = 'BAR',
}

type StringIsInEnum = 'FOO' extends `${MyEnum}` ? true : false; // true
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gKClAZgex1AXigHIAxAeXOIBoMoAjAQwCdCSAhAQQCUa0BfNGgAucAA7AoAZWHMAliADmASQDOykEkhsylYlGAAPYaAAmqqAAMAJCnhaI-S1AD8UWWEkAubIwA2qsAA3GgA9KGYUAB6LkA)